# Speaker Feedback and Popping

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, speakers

I am having a devil of a time with this issue on my 2020 Lenovo Laptop running Ubuntu 23.04

I have reviewed a lot of Ask Ubuntu solutions as far back as 18 and still with only partial success turning microphone off with terminal command;-

```
echo "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.con
```

This works but for some reason reverts after reboot no matter what I do.

Digging into a solution, #load-module module-suspend-on-idle - from Jayden on this thread, I decided to change the pulse config file thinking it would give me a permanent fix, the only config file I could find for Pulse Ubuntu 23.04 was in `/etc/pulse/client.conf`

The directory `/etc/pulse/client.conf.d` was empty.

So returning to the file client.conf, I noted the file `client-conf`  contained a lot of default/comment settings, none of which had anything to do with preventing ;load-module from idling.

Until I get this issue sorted I am saddled with having to re-set the microphone manually after each reboot and frankly this really is sub-optimal because then I have issues with my headset mic.

I'm really stuck any assist to solve this really painful bug would be greatly appreciated...!